# Explode pandas row by determined element

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandasql

I am using the MovieLens dataset and the movies csv looks like this:

[image]

How can I explode the genres column so that I have one genre per movie, so something like :

```
movieId       title                  genres

1            "Toy Story (1995)"      Adventure

1            "Toy Story (1995)"      Animation

1            "Toy Story (1995)"      Children

1            "Toy Story (1995)"      Comedy

1            "Toy Story (1995)"      Fantasy

2            "Jumanji (1995)"        Adventure
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas version 0.25.0 later we can do `explode`

```
df=df.assign(genres=df.genres.str.split('|')).explode('genres')
```

Comment: made a small change to your code, but still not run, cannot find the .splt method. Pandas 25.1

Comment: @Qubix that is split, type the answer by phone sry ~

Comment: TypeError: explode() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @Qubix here you go .